# Cannot get PowerShell string match to return True

Tags: string, powershell, match

I have an array of string values and am trying to run a loop to match (using `-eq` operator) and return true if another variable matches one of the string values in the array. Even though I know the values should match, the loop is returning false.

I am currently taking the PS objects and pulling out the string values of a particular property of the object for the matching. I tried other operators aside from `-eq`, including `-like` using a wildcard and `-match` but there is no change in behavior. I also am currently constructing a list using `$XXXX.Add($XXXX)`, but also had no luck with just populating an array with `=+`.

```
foreach ($Server in $UpdateGroupMembers) {
    if ($Server -eq $NodeName) {
        Write-Host "$Server is a match, loop terminated"
        return $true
        #break
    } else {
        Write-Host "There is no match"
        return $false
    }
}
```

`$NodeName` in the code above is a value that I know exists in the array/list, so I am quite lost.

Comment: It should work.  Can you show how $UpdateGroupMembers and $NodeName are being made?  `$list = 'one','two','three'; $target = 'two'; foreach ($i in $list) { $i -eq $target }`

Comment: Your code returns after the first element in the list, so not other elements get checked. Thus you'll always get "false" unless the very first element of your array matches `$NodeName`.

Comment: Why is it returning after the first element? That is where I think I am unclear. Is it because I called `return $true` specifically and not just `$true`?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) does exactly what the name suggests.

Comment: I am not a coder by trade, so things like that fly over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to check whether a list or array contains an item, you can use the `-in` operator:

```
if ($NodeName -in $UpdateGroupMembers) {
    "$NodeName is a match"
    $true
}
else {
    "There is no match"
    $false
}
```

If you truly only need a True or False return, then you can do a one-liner:

```
$NodeName -in $UpdateGroupMembers
```

Comment: It seems the real issue with my code as is was the use of the `return` keyword in my loop as Ansgar pointed out above. That being said, your solution is certainly an improvement on what I presented. I do not need the `Write-Host` bit at all, just the return.

Comment: And a follow up Q for the one liner: This seems to be using shorthand of some kind—is that correct? Is there a full fledged version that one line can be expanded to? I try to not use shortcuts or aliases in my code (idea being I understand what is occurring better).

Comment: The oneliner is not shorthand. It is a complete expression using the `-in` operator. The expression returns true or false always.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are exiting the function after hitting the first servername that doesn't match.
If my understanding is correct the code should look like:

```
$found= $false
foreach ($Server in $UpdateGroupMembers) {
    if ($Server -eq $NodeName) {
        Write-Host "$Server is a match, loop terminated"
        $found = $true
        break
}
if ($found -eq $false) {write-host "no match found for $NodeName "}
return $found
```

Make sure that **$NodeName** is a string and **$UpdateGroupMembers** is a collection of names not a collection of objects so you can compare them. I use something like `$UpdateGroupMembers | get-member` to see exactly what I am working with.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I had already pulled the desired property out of the object as a string for the items in $UpdateGroupMembers to ensure both I was matching strings so I knew I had that correct at least.